# Multiple Permissions in AndroidManifest?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, permissions, manifest

So I was wondering if there is a rule against having more than one **"uses-permission"** block in my app. EX:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

when I use this in my app, it crashes as soon as i click the button.

**NOTE:** my button saves a file to the SD card and uploads it to FTP (that's where i'm stuck - adding the internet part)

any thoughts?

Comment: No there is no rule against adding more than one rule, i think some problem in your code, upload your code in the question please.

Comment: Just complementing @Lucifer, also send  the logcat

Comment: Are you missing a permission? Also placement is critical. They have to preceed or follow the application statements. As with Licifer and Andre, you need to post some code. Manifest and the 'button' code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be as many uses-permissions in a manifest file as required by an application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use-permissions in a Manifest files as per your Requirement , its show the user when it download or install your application then Ask user to require permissions given permissions  before Application use.